# Где указывать имя таблицы в БД в Yii2?

Tags: yii2

В мануале на гитхабе (yii2/docs/guide-ru/start-databases.md) пишут:

Чтобы представлять и получать данные из таблицы country, создайте класс - потомок Active Record, под названием Country, и сохраните его в файле models/Country.php

Получаем потом данные так:

```
// получаем все строки из таблицы "country" и сортируем их по "name"
$countries = Country::find()->orderBy('name')->all();
```

В то же время видел варианты с запросами вида:

```
$var = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM `my`')->queryAll();
```

Какой вариант лучше, когда стоит применять первый, когда второй?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предпочтительней использовать модель, т.к. Yii2 сама построит запрос к БД. Так же такой подход облегчит переход с одной БД на другу. Плюсом к этому у вас на выходе будет массив объектов, а не просто массив данных, в этом так же есть преимущество, к примеру в модели вы сможете сделать обработку данных и не пихать эту логику в контроллер.
Второй вариант подойдет для каких-то специфических запросов БД или запросов которые не сможет построить `QueryBuilder`